# Bootstrap Button Dropdown Won't Remove Active Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I cannot find any answer or documentation for how to do this...

I have a [single dropdown button in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns). I am trying to have a reset button that resets the current selection to "Select All" on click. My current code is this:

```
$("#stateSelect select").val($("#stateSelect select option:first").val());
$("#stateSelect select").selectpicker("refresh");
```

This works to reset the selection value, but the dropdown does not set "Select All" to the active class. I have illustrated this in the following images:

Select a State:
[image: Initial Selection]

Click Reset button:
[image]

Arizona is still set as active:

[image]

I have tried to use this code to remove active class but it doesn't do anything. (Yes I have tested and it does successfully find the object.)

```
$("#stateSelect > div.dropdown > div.dropdown-menu > div.inner > ul.dropdown-menu > li.selected.active > a.active").removeClass('active');
```

How do I reset the active selection to either "Select All" or deselect all?

Edit: My assumption is that the way bootstrap dropdown works may not work for my use case. Here is what the dropdown generates:
[image]

As you can tell, there is a  object. But there is also  tag that generates when the dropdown is clicked and shown.

Comment: Add `$("#stateSelect select").selectpicker('deselectAll')` before refreshing.

Comment: tried that before, unfortunately, doesn't work. If I do an inspect, it seems that there are 2 components to the dropdown. The first is a <select> to populate the options and the second is the <ul> list to show what is selected. The dropdown showing the active <a> is under the ul and uses aria properties...not sure if that helps

Comment: Have tried `$("#stateSelect").selectpicker("refresh");`